# Second order ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question about second-order ordinary differential equations. what is the proper method for solving these equations? And in a case, if we have a set of these equations with only one unknown function ($f(r)$) as the following form:
$
1) a1 f(x)+b2 f'(x)+c1 f''(x)+d1 f(x) f'(x)+e1 f'(x) f''(x)+h1 f(x) f''(x)=0\\
2) a2 f(x)+b3 f'(x)+c3 f''(x)+d2 f(x) f'(x)+e2 f'(x) f''(x)+h2 f(x) f''(x)=0\\
3) a3 f(x)+b3 f'(x)+c3 f''(x)+d3 f(x) f'(x)+e3 f'(x) f''(x)+h3 f(x) f''(x)=0\\
4) a4 f(x)+b4 f'(x)+c4 f''(x)+d4 f(x) f'(x)+e4 f'(x) f''(x)+h4 f(x) f''(x)=0\\
$
Can we solve that? And How can we understand if these equations have a solution?
Also, I have the following equations which is a more complicated case
\begin{equation}
\pmb{\text{eq1}=\frac{(a_1) l^2+r^2}{\left(l^2+r^2\right)^2}+\frac{(a_2) f'[r]^2}{8 f[r]^2}+\frac{-1+r
f'[r]}{\left(l^2+r^2\right) f[r]}=0}\\
\pmb{\text{eq2}=\frac{(a_3) l^2 f[r]}{l^2+r^2}+r f'[r]-\frac{(a_4) \left(l^2+r^2\right) f'[r]^2}{8 f[r]}+\frac{1}{2}
\left(l^2+r^2\right) f''[r]=0}
\end{equation}
What are your suggestions to solve these equations?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "proper method" in general. What can be done is identify classes of equations and then use a variety of methods that are known to work for those classes. For example, linear equations with nice enough coefficents can be solved via Laplace transforms or, or homogenous scalar equations may be integrated with suitable variable transformations and then quadratures (like what you do for first order homogenous), in the case of Bessel type equations, you can calculate a point transformation that lets you transform the equation into a normal form. etc.

The most general methods however for integrating equations in general are either by identifying and studying certain Hilbert/Banach spaces associated with the equations or to use symmetries reduce to order of the equation (this is usually done through coordinate transformations). In general, you cannot find the exact form of a solution because it doesn't exist however so you just do casework for initial value problems.

In the case of your listed equation, since there is more than one equation you should start by looking for compatibility conditions. Second, there's also the algebra perspective of this, you can look for combinations of the equations that are nicer to deal with or perhaps a combination that yields a first order equation, see if you can solve this, and then substitute it into all the equations to verify that it works and then do all the specific casework associated with whatever conditions you have to have in order to integrate the equation. You might find that a solution however does not exist depending on the values of the coefficients.

Comment: thank you very much, I have edited my question. Do you have any idea about these new equations?

Comment: The second equation is homogeneous in $f[r]$ and its derivatives. So we can transform $f\to k f$, $f'\to kf'$, $f''\to k f''$ and $eq2 \to k \cdot eq 2.$ Because of this, the equation is a function of variables of the form $\frac{f'}{f}$ and its derivatives. So what you do is set $f'(r) = u(r) f(r)$ and then as a consequence $f''(r) = [u'(r) + u(r)^2 ] f(r)$. Doing you get either $f(r)=0$ or a first order equation involve $u(r)$. Since you have explicit r's however, so case work should be done there if no obvious methods pop out.

Comment: With a little bit of algebra it should be in the reduced form $(\ell^2+r^2)u'(r) +  2r u(r) = -\frac{2a_3 \ell^2}{(\ell^2+r^2)} + (\ell^2+r^2)(2a_r-1) u(r)^2 $. Left hand side is a total derivative. But we have problems in the right hand side of course. If $a_3=0 $ or $\ell=0$, then the form is conducive to Bernoulli's method. If $a_4 = 1/2$, then you can just treat this as a linear equation. But otherwise, it's not clear how to solve it in this form. We can however reduce the equation more by changing variables. Let $v(r) = (\ell^2+r^2)u(r)$.

Comment: The equation then becomes $\frac{dv}{dr} = (2a_4 -1)\frac{v(r)^2}{\ell^2 + r^2} - \frac{2a_3\ell^2}{\ell^2+r^2} $. This is nicer because it is in a separable form and we can write the integrals $\int \frac{dv}{ (2 a_4 -1)v^2 - 2 a_3\ell^2} = \int \frac{dr}{\ell^2 +r^2} $. This is much nicer formally since you can just use calc 2 to solve for $v(r)$, then find out $u(r) = \frac{v(r)}{\ell^2+r^2}$, then because $f'(r) = u(r) f(r)$, $f(r) = K e^{\int u(r) dr} .$ Next step is to plug the solution into eq1 and that you tell you whether or not it's a solution and conditions on the constants.

Comment: Thank you very much it was very helpful, but I have just one question, you wrote $(2a_4 -1)$ but I think it must be $\frac{a_4}{4}-1$, is it correct?

Comment: You're right. I dropped the 8 by accident.

Comment: Also, make sure to a complete casework for $a_3, a_4, \ell$ since this will determine the form of the solution in each case for the integral on the left-hand-side. Fortunately $\ell=0$ and $a_3=0$ are close to the same case. There's just other cases: $a_4/4-1 =0$; $a/4-1 > 0$, $a_3<0$; $a/4-1>0$, $a_3>0$; etc.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Very helpful!